# how can I remove certain categories from my dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am trying to make a ml model that can predict the category of the given sentence using MNB but in the training data there are unwanted classes in it . How can I remove that data

[This is the datset iam using](https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-category-dataset/)

this dataset does not belong to me

> Misra, Rishabh and Prahal Arora. "Sarcasm Detection using Hybrid Neural Network."arXivpreprint arXiv:1908.07414 (2019).

> Misra, Rishabh and Jigyasa Grover. "Sculpting Data for ML: The first act of Machine Learning." ISBN 9798585463570 (2021).

I want to remove certain categories like 'US.NEWS' , 'POLITICS' etc.. how can I do that?

I tried to read the data by loading it using json module in python but somehow that too is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Popular library in python for data manipulation is [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

You can load [load](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) this json with the function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("path/to/the/file")
```

And then later you can [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns you want:

```
df.drop(["US.NEWS", "POLITICS"], axis=1)
```

---

Of course you can use other libraries like [polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) and [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/#)!

Comment: they are values inside a column named "category" I want to remove values inside of that column

Comment: df['categories'] will give "POLITICS","SCIENCE" etc.. here I want to remove "POLITICS" from the column how can I do that?